# How to compare two enums?

Tags: java

I have two enums:

```
public enum UserType {
    USER,
    EMPLOYER

}
```

```
public enum UserDetails {
    USER,
    EMPLOYER
}
```

I try to compare this by this:

```
if(UserType.USER.equals(UserDetails.USER)){
    return true;
}
```

but i can't because, my `equals()` throw me this:

```
equals() between objects of inconvertible types 'UserType' and 'UserDetails'
```

so, how can I compare two values from two diffrent enums?

Comment: You can't, they are different types.  How did you expect to compare them?  What is your end goal?

Comment: Just because they're *named* the same doesn't mean they *are* the same. You shouldn't really be doing that kind of comparison in the first place, it suggests a design smell.

Comment: I need to use in `@RequestParam` enums, which can be compare to another value from enums

Comment: Sounds like weird design to me.

Comment: I would use something like an `ImmutableBiMap<UserType, UserDetails>` to store and look up corresponding values.

Comment: A *highly* questionable thing to do would be `if (((Object) UserType.USER).equals(UserDetails.USER))`; but that's going to be false anyway.

Comment: @AndyTurner: A map will take memory and, more important, will be slower.

Comment: @mentallurg that's the least important thing to consider here.

Comment: @Kayaman: How do you know what is important for the author? Only the author should tell us how important it is.

Comment: @mentallurg I use my experience as well as the fact that the author is trying to compare enums by name to draw certain conclusions. Also while it may be important to the author, whether it's important in reality is a different thing. If you write up a JMH performance comparison between `enum` and `BiMap` and consider the scenarios where it would make an **actual** difference, I'm sure you'll realise your "more important" claim is moot.

Comment: keep calm guys :) answer from @Alex is enough :) thanks for answers and this discussion

Comment: If you actually explained what you're doing with your `@RequestParam`, there's probably a better solution than what you're doing. This has [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to compare their names

```
if(UserType.USER.name().equals(UserDetails.USER.name())){
    return true;
}
```

Reading other answers i've decided to give more extended answer. I have to agree thats such solution is not good enough, cause it's not about enums - it's about string comparing. Enums may be changed and everythig will not work properly. Ok.
I think that there could be better solutions - of course:

- Use only one type of enum - it's perfect i think(but author has different enums)
- Compare names of enums - well it's working but realy not "clever" use of enum
- Make some mapping - why not - but its hard linking of two different enums and it is not good enough

```
enum UserType {
   USER,
   EMPLOYER;

   public boolean isLike(UserDetails details) {
       switch (this) {
           case USER:
               return details == UserDetails.USER;
           case EMPLOYER:
               return details == UserDetails.EMPLOYER;
       }
       return false;
   }
}

enum UserDetails {
   USER,
   EMPLOYER;
}

if(UserType.USER.isLike(UserDetails.USER)){
           // do something
}
```

So we see that's there is no better decision than rewrite the code and make only one `enum`. But everything depends on the issue:

- We don't know why there are two enums - perhaps author supporting legacy code
- We don't know why author has to compare these different enums
- Does proposed decision solve this concrete problem - **yes**. Is it good - **no**

Comment: Yes, this is possible. But the use of `enum` in this way is odd. It would suggest that those are possibly the same type, not two different types. Or some kind of "clever" use of enum.

Comment: @Alex I suggest you add a discussion of your comment to your answer. I also suggest adding a note to your current answer along the line of the [comment  by Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068168/how-to-compare-two-enums/62068478#comment109777038_62068253), that comparing enum names is an odd and awkward use of Java enums.

Answer (score 6):

## Different types

The [enum in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is a [class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29), albeit a slightly special kind of class. A class defines a [type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type).

Unless related by [inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) or by [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), different types cannot be compared for equality. A `String` cannot be equal to a `LocalDate` which cannot be equal to a `DataSource`.

Likewise, an object of enum `UserType` cannot be equal to an object of enum `UserDetails`. [Apples to oranges](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apples_and_oranges), not equal by definition.  So, your Question is senseless, technically.

The fact that some enum classes happen to share names on some of their constants has no meaning, it is just coincidence that your two enums share the name `USER` or `EMPLOYER`. The enum [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) bundled with Java defines a constant named [`APRIL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html#APRIL). I might define another enum with an object also named `APRIL`. But that does not make them equal.

Asking this question suggests that you have a problem with your design. Perhaps you should post another Question on that design issue if it has but already been addressed on Stack Overflow. As [commented by Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62068168/how-to-compare-two-enums/62068478?noredirect=1#comment109777968_62068168), your Question seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

The other Answers suggesting you:

- Compare the strings of the names of the enum constants.
- Compare the ordinal position of the constants within the enum definition.

…are misguided. Those approaches violate the purpose of enums in Java, which is to provide a [type-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) identity of certain values known at [compile-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time).

- If you are **comparing the names** of the constants, then you might as well be using mere `String` objects rather than enums.
- If you are **comparing ordinal numbers**, then you might as well be using mere integer numbers rather than enums.

Both cases are fragile, resulting in runtime failures if you make a change to one enum without matching the other. And in both cases you have lost the usefulness of the enum, transmogrifying the enum into a confusing level of indirection for a string or `int`.

Comment: Try not be too formal and try to understand the intention. The intention is to establish some kind of equivalence. Yes, it if formulated not perfectly. But the goal is clear.

Comment: @mentallurg How is the author to understand the incompatibility of equality-testing without a formal definition of the technical issue?

Comment: @mentallurg the intention is to work around the type safety of enums. We're trying to explain this is poor design.

Comment: @BasilBourque: "The other Answers .. misguided"  - this is not correct. Enum in request (e.g. in a REST controller) ensures that only predefined values can be passed as a parameter. On the other hand there is business logic that uses its independent classes including enums. In the simplest case (or in the initial phase of the project) these enums contains identical constants. I don't need to explain you why we don't want to mix different layers. Thus, to call a service from REST controller, you need to map values from one Enum to another...

Comment: ... In the simplest case, when Enums contain identical values, it is absolutely sufficient to map them in a single line of code using the names of Enum contants. If Enums are different, then of course a map suggested by @Andy Turner can be a better approach.

Comment: @Kayaman: Poor design is, when a single Enum is used across 2-3 layers, from JPA to REST controller. Good design separates classes even if they may look similar. E.g. if you prefer good design you don't use JPA entities in the REST layer, but introduce some DTOs, even if they have fields similar or identical to JPA entities. The same good design requires you to separate Enums in different layers. And when you have 2 Enums, you need to map one to another.

Comment: @mentallurg are you saying you have a separate `enum` for a different layer? That's horrible. An `enum` is a simple value object that doesn't care about the layer. It's not at all the same thing as say passing an entity in the controller. Your example would be like having a different `String` object just because you're going to a different layer.

Comment: @mentallurg perhaps you didn't understand. Entities don't belong to the controller, but `enum`s can go anywhere. You don't need a `ControllerEnum.FOO` and `JPAEnum.FOO` for example. They're both the *same* `FOO`. I don't know what your "extend enumeration" story is. They're not supposed to be so complex that a developer would need 1 day to do anything. It sounds like you may have serious design issues instead of just design smells.

Comment: @Kayaman: If you want to continue our discussion, please create a chat :) I will be glad to discuss.

Comment: Sorry, too tired right now....enums shouldn't require this much discussion. They aren't *that* interesting.